# Does not work creation an envelope through Docusign SDK PHP

Tags: php, docusignapi

Using the example of [CreateEnvelope sample code](http://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Create%20and%20Send.htm)

I receive a message:

> Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes
>   (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Using the method of `guid()` of SDK, which returns a string in the form `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

I receive a message:

> The 'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0:ID' element is invalid - The
>   value '0 'is invalid according to its datatype

What is the format for the recipient ID is valid?

Answer (score 1):

In DocuSign, when you are adding recipients to your envelopes you need at least 3 pieces of data to uniquely identify each recipient.  You need to set recipient `name`, `email`, and `recipientId`. (If you are using the [Embedding feature](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features) then you need to set the `CaptiveInfo` as well for SOAP or the `clientUserId` if using REST)

The `recipientId` is user-defined, meaning you can set it to whatever you like- however it needs to be a non-negative number such as 1, 2, 1000, 2000.  I believe the data type for the recipientId is string so you're not limited to just numbers either.

However, **0** is the one value that you can not set it to.  So try changing the value of your `recipientId` to `1` or `2` or `one` or `two` or `1abc` or `2def` and see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
$r = new Recipient();
$r->ID = '1';
$r->UserName = 'john';
$r->SignerName = 'John Doe';
$r->Email = 'john@example.com';
$r->Type = RecipientTypeCode::Signer;
$r->RoutingOrder = 1;
$r->RequireIDLookup = false;
$r->CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo();
$r->CaptiveInfo->ClientUserId = '1';
...
```

And getting an error message:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] 358101: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

If I use the following code:

```
$uid = $this->getUid();
$r->ID = $uid;
...
$r->CaptiveInfo->ClientUserId = $uid;
...
```

$this->getUid() using the method of `guid()` of SDK, which returns a string in the form `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

Getting an error message:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Validation error: The 'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0:ID' element is invalid - The value '0' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0:LocalId' - Value '0' was either too large or too small for PositiveInteger.